# Add a character in between regex

Tags: regex, awk, sed, notepad++

I have a very long list of data and trying to convert into a csv and the only delimiter is a lowercase always precedes a uppercase.  So I am trying to add a comma in between `[a-z][A-Z]`.  Is this possible using Notepad++?  Should I just use awk/sed from shell?  Because right now it finds it, but erases the two characters and adds the comma.

Comment: `sed` can do that, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem using `([a-z])([A-Z])` so you can replace using `$1,$2` :

[image: notepad++]

## regex demo

Answer (score 0):

Using N++, without capturing groups you are able to benefit from lookarounds:

Find:

```
(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])
```

Replace with:

```
,
```

Note: *Match case* option should be checked.